# CoreData error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: Cannot set value for attribute with undefined type: property ... for optional UUID

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsexception

I have a CoreData entity (named `Canvas`)which contains an attribute: `selectedCardID` of type `UUID?`.

My CoreData entity is managed by my own `NSManagedObject` Subclass with the following line:

```
extension Canvas {

    @NSManaged public var selectedCardID: UUID?

}
```

When attempting to set a value to `selectedCardID` I get the following error

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot set value for attribute with undefined type: property = "selectedCardID"; entity = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x2823f0160>) name Canvas

I don't understand what the error message means by *undefined type* when I've added `UUID?` to to both the subclass and `xcdatamodel` file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@NSManaged public var selectedCardID: String?`

Comment: UUID is certainly a valid type for Core Data. Did you add it now, maybe you simply need to clean your build folder and/or remove the project folder under DerivedData so that Xcode is not using an old version when building.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've tried that but to no avail. For now converting between `uuidString` and `UUID` as recommended by @Sh_Khan seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Could you explain how you set it? I use UUID in several places in my current project although not as an optional attribute if that could be relevant.

Comment: Is there any more to that error message? It seems like that's only part of what it would say.